# Python threading - do something while join()

Tags: python, multithreading

Python 2.6.6

I hava a list of threads to be executed and the main code will wait (Threading.join()) until they're all finished.

```
>>> for thread in threadList:
...     thread.start()
>>> for t in threadList:
...     t.join()
```

Is there a way to print messages like "running..." while the main code waits the end of the threads?

I want to print the same thing ("running...") second after second until the threads are all done.

Thanks.

---

**SOLVED**

Implemented solution:

```
>>> for thread in threadList:
...     thread.start()
>>> string = "running"
>>> while any(t.is_alive() for t in threadList):
...    sys.stdout.write("\r%s" % string)
...    sys.stdout.flush()
...    string = string + "."                     #this may not be the best way
...    time.sleep(0.5)
```

In my case, the extra time of "time.sleep(0.5)" is not an issue, although it's not the most recommended.

This generates the output:

```
running........
```

The dots after "running" will be printed one after one, on the same line, while there is any thread alive. Exactly as I expected!

Based on the answers of @Manuel Jacob and @Alex Hall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thread.join() is blocking by design.  Instead of using Thread.join(), you could periodically call Thread.is_alive().

Your example adapted:

```
for thread in threadList:
    thread.start()
while any(thread.is_alive() for thread in threadList):
    print('running...')
    time.sleep(1)
```

As was pointed out in the comments, this can cause up to one second of extra delay, when the last thread finishes during the sleep.

Comment: This will cause up to a second of extra waiting.

Comment: Thanks, Manuel Jacob! It worked just fine. I'll update the question to show my results.

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

threadList = [Thread(target=lambda: sleep(3)), Thread(target=lambda: sleep(5))]

for thread in threadList:
    thread.start()

def check_running():
    while True:
        alive = sum(thread.is_alive() for thread in threadList)
        if not alive:
            break
        print '%s threads still running...' % alive
        sleep(1)

Thread(target=check_running).start()

for t in threadList:
    t.join()
```

Output:

```
2 threads still running...
2 threads still running...
2 threads still running...
1 threads still running...
1 threads still running...
```

---

Alternatively:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

threadList = [Thread(target=lambda: sleep(3), name='Alice'), Thread(target=lambda: sleep(5), name='Bob')]

for thread in threadList:
    thread.start()

for t in threadList:
    while True:
        t.join(timeout=1)
        if not t.is_alive():
            break
        print('%s is still running...' % t.name)
```

Output:

```
Alice is still running...
Alice is still running...
Bob is still running...
```

Comment: you should also be joining the `check_running` thread at the end

Comment: @njzk2 why? That will cause the program to take longer to finish and we don't care about it.

Comment: just to make sure everything is closed, and you could replace the loop of joins with a single join to the monitor thread

Comment: @njzk2 if there's any chance that the monitor thread has a bug and doesn't terminate, I'd prefer to have it hanging around taking up a small amount of resources than leave the program stuck forever. It'll also cause unnecessary waiting.

Comment: Thanks, Alex Hall! Your second solution ("Alternavely") was the best fit for the problem. 

I've implemented solution of @Manuel Jacob because it's clearer for others to understand, and I need this simplicity so that my partners (not Python programmers) may be able to give support to the code.